# How to run C code/file with MINGW?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

OK, I just began learning C language, and I read a lot of people suggest to use MinGW as a compiler. I downloaded, installed it and set it correctly (I think) and set the path. everything seems to be OK.
My problem is that I can't find a way to run a C file from the CMD, when I do something like this:

```
C:\>gcc a\c1.c
```

nothing appear on the CMD

In c1.c file I have the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("this is a test.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried tcc compiler and when using it this way:

```
C:\>tcc a\c1.c
```

it outputs the following:

```
this is a test.
```

How can I make MinGW output that the same way?
I looked in the MinGW/gcc manual and HowTos and couldn't find a way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`gcc filename.c` compiles and links your file -- but it doesn't write the executable to `hello.exe` as you might expect (and of course it doesn't execute it).

And, as is the convention for Unix-based tools, `gcc` generally doesn't print anything unless something went wrong.  The fact that it finished and you got a new `C:\>` prompt is what tells you that it succeeded.

On Unix, for historical reasons, the default name of an executable is `a.out` (it stands for "assembler output").  For MinGW, the default name is `a.exe`, since Windows requires a `.exe` suffix for executable files.

So after running `gcc a\c1.c`, you can run `a.exe` or `.\a.exe` to run the program.

Or, better, as Doug suggests, you can use the `-o` option to specify the name of the generated executable file.

(If you want to run just the compiler and generate an object file rather than an executable, use `gcc -c`.)

Note that this behavior (not printing anything unless there's a problem, naming the executable file `a.out` or `a.exe`, etc.) is defined by the gcc compiler in particular. It's not a feature of the C language. Other C compilers might or might not behave similarly.

Comment: Thanks Keith for the explaining. Another question though: when I use `gcc -c`, it outputs an object file as you mentioned, but that doesn't print anything. And if I run `gcc c1.o` it create a(n) `a.exe` file, then when running `a.exe` file, it prints the sentence `this is a test.`, is this normal behavior? Or am I doing something wrong? If I understand correctly, there is no way to print anything in gcc without running the `.exe` file, right?

Comment: Yes, that's all perfectly normal.  gcc stays quiet unless it has something important to say.  Just as an experiment, try introducing an error, deleting a semicolon from your source file, and compiling again, and see what gcc says.

Comment: GCC is a compiler. It would mostly print warnings and error messages (and you should avoid that). Once compiled, your program do whataver you instructed it to do. If the source code contains output functions like printf or puts which happens to be executed, it will indeed output something. But your program may also crash or behave incorrectly. Correcting that is called debugging.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Keith. I guess I have to play with C for a while before I get used to it and understand how it works. Your help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: It's important to be aware that the behavior of gcc (`-c` to inhibit linking, `a.exe` as the default executable name, minimal or no visible output) is *not* defined by the C language.  It's just the idiosyncrasies of one particular compiler.  Others may behave differently and still be perfectly valid C compilers.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, thanks for the useful comment.
Thanks again Keith

Answer (score 1):

tcc is compiling, linking, and executing your C file.

gcc is compiling your C file, but not linking or executing it.

Try:

```
C:\>gcc -o a\ci.exe a\c1.c
```

Followed by

```
a\ci.exe
```

Once you have that figured out, you will want to learn about [`make`](http://www.gnu.org/s/make/)

Comment: That's not quite correct.  It compiles *and links*, but the name of the generated executable isn't what you might expect.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are a newbie, I strongly suggest you to compile with the `-Wall` flag (to get all warnings GCC can give you) and with the `-g` flag (to get a debuggable executable). Take the habit to improve your code till you get no warnings any more. And indeed, learn how to use `make`. If you want the compiler to [optimize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler_optimization) the generated code, replace `-g` with `-O2` (but do that once the program is correctly running, and you have debugged it).